# Bind9 unable to resolve external nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, dns-zone, dns-server

I have set up a DNS Server within my company's LAN.

Local nameservers works correctly, however those outside such as google.com are not resolved...

By running **dig google.it** I get this result:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> google.it ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got
> answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 5354 ;;
> flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232 ;;
> QUESTION SECTION: ;google.it.         IN  A
>
> ;; Query time: 71 msec ;; SERVER: 192.168.83.4#53(192.168.83.4) ;;
> WHEN: Thu Nov 03 08:59:41 CET 2022 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38

My current LAN config is:

> - Gateway:    192.168.83.1
> - Subnet:     255.255.255.0
> - Web Server: 192.168.83.3
> - DNS Server: 192.168.83.4
> - Storage 1:  192.168.83.5
> - Storage 2:  192.168.83.6

Etc..

As for Bind this is my config: (***I replaced my real domain with the mydomain.it keyword***)

> /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
acl trusted {
        192.168.83.0/24;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        allow-query { localhost; trusted; };
        allow-transfer { localhost; };
        forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

> /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "dc1.mydomain.it" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.dc1.mydomain.it";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

> /etc/bind/zones/db.dc1.mydomain.it

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dc1.mydomain.it. admin.dc1.mydomain.it. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS      ns1.dc1.mydomain.it.

ns1.dc1.mydomain.it.           IN      A       192.168.83.4
www.dc1.mydomain.it.           IN      A       192.168.83.3
storage1.dc1.mydomain.it.      IN      A       192.168.83.5
storage2.dc1.mydomain.it.      IN      A       192.168.83.6
```

Etc..

> /etc/bind/zones/db.192.168

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dc1.mydomain.it. admin.dc1.mydomain.it. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS      ns1.dc1.mydomain.it.

4.83    IN      PTR     ns1.dc1.mydomain.it.
3.83    IN      PTR     www.dc1.mydomain.it.
5.83    IN      PTR     storage1.dc1.mydomain.it.
6.83    IN      PTR     storage2.dc1.mydomain.it.
```

I state that I am not very experienced with Bind, can anyone tell me where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: Your config looks correct to me. What happens when you try to resolve from the server itself?

Comment: The code `SERVFAIL` could mean multiple things, including configuration issues and also issues outside of your server. Do the logs give any interesting records on a failed resolution or start-up?

Comment: At the moment I'm abroad, as soon as I get back I'll try and let you know, thanks for your answer!